# how to append access token in fql query

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, access-token

I am using this code for fql query to get user insights for the page he admins.

```
    $fql  = "SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=". $url . " AND metric='page_fans_country' AND end_time=1398665793 AND period=2592000";
    $apifql="https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=".urlencode($fql);
    $lc_json=file_get_contents($apifql);
    $lc = json_decode($lc_json);
```

It throws error 104 and this error code says I must use access token while I have read_insights permission also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get access token by using facebook object and just embed it to your fql query

```
<?php
    $token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $apifql="https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=".urlencode($fql)."&access_token=".$token;
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your effort but it still shows the 104 error as :
Array ( [error_code] => 104 [error_msg] => Requires valid signature [request_args] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => method [value] => fql.query ) [1] => Array ( [key] => format [value] => json ) [2] => Array ( [key] => query [value] => SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=627309577352060 AND metric='page_fans_country' AND end_time=1398665793 AND period=2592000 ) [3] => Array ( [key] => access_token [value] => ) ) )

Comment: if i am not wrong it seems that your access_token value is blank. You can generate access token for test from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: sure, thanks for your notice I was not sending the token as a parameter to my function but now the array is blank, what could be the issue.

Comment: also try this https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts you will get access_token for your page

Comment: I am using 
SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=627309577352060 AND metric='page_fans' AND end_time=1398665793 AND period=2592000
in FB tools explorer and getting blank data, while this test page has 2 likes

Comment: Did you ask for "manage_pages" and "read_insights" permissions?

Comment: is your likes to that page older? i guess fb will show insights after at least 30 likes and also it may take some hours to show your data

Answer (score 0):

You should use the

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=...
```

endpoint as described here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/#read). This should do the trick:

```
$apifql="https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=".urlencode($fql)."&access_token=".$facebook->getAccessToken();
```